# Do const class methods prevent assigning variables outside of the class?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have solved the problem of getting this code to compile by removing the "const". However, why does it seem I cannot assign non-class members in a const class method in this specific situation? It probably is part of the class; though, I do not understand why.

I got my code to compile, but I am confused at this situation.

Below, are some declarations in the class.

```
using twoDList = multimap<string,string>;
twoDList SomeMultiMap;
```

This will work when I take off the "const". Or at least compile. Though, here I am just assigning iterators declared only in this function. Using namespace std by the way.

```
bool object::foo(string a, string b) const
{
    pair<object::twoDList::iterator,object::twoDList::iterator> wordRange;
    wordRange = SomeMultiMap.equal_range(a);

    object::twoDList::iterator it = wordRange.first;

    //...
    //...
    //...
}
```

I expected this function to compile without removing the const, but it does not compile.

Edit: here are the compilation errors, and I am using this on linux command line.

```
g++ -g -DDEBUG -std=c++11 -c test1.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from test1.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>& std::pair<_T1, _T2>::operator=(std::pair<_U1, _U2>&&) [with _U1 = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >; _U2 = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >; _T1 = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >; _T2 = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >]’:
test1.cpp:15:15:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:188:10: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >’ and ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >’)
    first = std::forward<_U1>(__p.first);
          ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:188:10: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/map:60:0,
                 from test1.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:157:12: note: std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >& std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >::operator=(const std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >&)
     struct _Rb_tree_iterator
            ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:157:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >’ to ‘const std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >&’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:157:12: note: std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >& std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >::operator=(std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >&&)
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:157:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >’ to ‘std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >&&’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from test1.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:189:11: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >’ and ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >’)
    second = std::forward<_U2>(__p.second);
           ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:189:11: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/map:60:0,
                 from test1.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:157:12: note: std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >& std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >::operator=(const std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >&)
     struct _Rb_tree_iterator
            ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:157:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >’ to ‘const std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >&’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:157:12: note: std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >& std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >::operator=(std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >&&)
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:157:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >’ to ‘std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >&&’
makefile:10: recipe for target 'test1.o' failed
make: *** [test1.o] Error 1
```

Edit: more edits to fix scope operators. Also, added the fact that I am using namespace std if that helps.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the compilation error?

Comment: `std::multimap`s `equal_range()` has overloads that are not `const`.   If the best match is to call the non-`const` overloads, your code will not compile.    By specifying your `pair` to contain `iterator`s rather than `const_iterator`s you make the non-`const` version a better match.    So you also need to change `pair<object::twoDList::iterator,object::twoDList::iterator> wordRange` to `pair<object::twoDList::const_iterator,object::twoDList::const_iterator> wordRange`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `const` after a member function's parameter list is a promise not to change the class object via the `this` pointer.  The type of `this` becomes `const ClassType*` instead of just `ClassType*`.  (Like any pointer-to-const or reference-to-const, this only means the thing can't be changed using that pointer or reference, not that the object is permanently const or can't be changed by other means.)

To say a class object is treated as `const` means that all its members (except any marked `mutable`) are treated as `const`.  And since in a member function definition a plain non-static member name `N` actually means the same as `this->N`, members named that way are treated as `const` when the function declaration has a `const` after the parameter list.

So inside `bool object::foo(string a, string b) const`, the name `SomeMultiMap`, being a member of `object`, is treated as a `const SomeMultiMap`.  And [`equal_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range) gives a `pair<const_iterator, const_iterator>` when the `multimap` object expression is `const`, or a `pair<iterator, iterator>` only when the object expression is not `const`.

So this may work instead (depending on what you need to do afterward):

```
std::pair<twoDList::const_iterator,twoDList::const_iterator> wordRange;
wordRange = SomeMultiMap.equal_range(a);

twoDList::const_iterator it = wordRange.first;
```

(Note you usually don't need the `object::` prefixes, since the member function body is in its class's scope.)

Although I would just define these variables with `auto` instead, avoiding the need to get the type exactly right, and saving on typing out those long iterator names.

```
auto wordRange = SomeMultiMap.equal_range(a);
auto it = wordRange.first;
```